# Json error not printing exact data

Tags: ajax, json, jsp

i am trying to get data from json file but when iam calling data.user its printing undefined and if iam printing data its printing json whole data ....

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax_get_json(){  var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 hr.open("GET", "mylist.json", true);   hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json",true); 
    hr.responseType= "JSON";hr.onreadystatechange = function() 
{if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200)
 {alert('1');var data=hr.responseText;alert('2');
  alert(data.user);
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = data;  }}  
        hr.send(null);  results .innerHTML = "request ...";}

    </script></head><body><div id="results"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">ajax_get_json();</script>
```

Comment: This question is not related to Java. Or PHP. Or JSP.

Comment: @Penumatsa,Can you please show me json data when you printing data.So I can help you !

Comment: this is my json data   {
 "user":"rakesh"
}

Comment: if iam calling data.user it showing undefined but if iam trying too call data its showing whole data plz help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

The response returned is a JSON string.

To convert into a JavaScript object, the response text has to be parsed using `JSON.parse()`

Try the following code

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

alert(parsedData.user);
```